# Get data from one to many relation as array

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with `one-to-many` relationship. I would like to get the data from the table with many as an array.

The 2 tables look like this:

```
    Users
_____________
| id | name |
|____|______|
| 1  | John |
|____|______|

    Posts
________________________
| id | title | user_id |
|____|_______|_________|
| 1  | post1 |    1    |
|____|_______|_________|
| 2  | post2 |    1    |
|____|_______|_________|
```

I can get the posts for each user using:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.name, p.title, p.id as post_id 
FROM users u 
JOIN posts p ON u.id = p.user_id 
WHERE u.id = :id";
```

This would return the following data:

```
_________________________________
| id |   name  | title | post_id |
|____|_________|_______|_________|
| 1  |   John  | post1 |    1    |
|____|_________|_______|_________|
| 1  |   John  | post2 |    2    |
|____|_________|_______|_________|
```

The id and name are duplicated with each row and I don't need this data, So I want to get the posts data  as array on 1 row like:

```
________________________
| id |   name  | posts |
|____|_________|_______|
| 1  |   John  | array |
|____|_________|_______|
```

Result would be something like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => John 
        [posts] =>  Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [title] => post1
                [post_id] => 1
            )
            [1]=> Array (
                [title] => post2
                [post_id] => 2
            )     
        )
     ) 
)
```

Is that possible with SQL or I need to handle the data with PHP to look like this result?

Comment: How do you fetch the data? I'd suggest you to use the `\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` keyword. For example like this:  `$result = $sql->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);`

Comment: I tested with MYSQL directly. But with PHP I use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: `array` isn't a sql datatype. You could use `group_concat` (in mysql) to join child records with a delimiter and then parse them apart, or select multiple rows with joins. In either case, you'll handle it in code.

Answer (score 3):

Forming such Php array could be tricky.
But json objects are quite similar.

> ```
> create table Users (
>  id int primary key auto_increment, 
>  name varchar(30)
>  );
>
> create table Posts (
>  id int primary key auto_increment, 
>  title varchar(30), 
>  user_id int
>  );
>
> insert into Users (name) values ('John');
> insert into Posts (title, user_id) values 
> ('Post 1', 1), ('Post 2', 1);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT u.id, u.name
> , concat('[', group_concat(JSON_OBJECT('title', p.title, 'post_id', p.id) order by p.id separator ','), ']') as posts
> FROM Users u
> JOIN Posts p ON u.id = p.user_id
> GROUP BY u.id, u.name
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name | posts                                                                
> -: | :--- | :--------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | John | [{"title": "Post 1", "post_id": 1},{"title": "Post 2", "post_id": 2}]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1e4e059d9b338e9a12ba33db1a50455b)*

Comment: How to decode this JSON object?. I tried `json_decode($data[0]['answers']);` and `json_decode($data[0]['answers'], true);`. But I get `Null`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to code php. Nor what that json_decode is expecting. Maybe it needs to be surrounded by square brackets to make it look like an array of objects? `[{...}, {...}]`